Solana Pay Link for Payment with Wallet on computer
I am looking into Solana Pay right now for a web app where you can buy shares. I worked through different tutorials but in the end it is always showing that you can convert it into QR Code and then scan with wallet (mobile). This works fine. But can you use Solana Pay to generate a link that is usable on desktop? Like not generating a QR Code, but having a button/link that you press and the wallet opens on desktop? Maybe I'm blind but I'm struggling to find an answer. Or is for desktop the "standard" way with wallet adapter the way to go?
